# how do i create a package without this error?

Tags: java, class

Error: Could not find or load main class Main

```
package movieTheatre;

public class movieFile{

  int popcornPrice;
  int discountTick;
  static int ticketPrice = 12;

  public static void (String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Your ticket cost is: "+ticketPrice);
  }
}
```

I would like to accomplish this. 
Write a code for a parent class that contains at least three variables of at least two types, and at least one method.

Comment: You forgot the method name: `public static void main( String[] args )'

Comment: I am aware but it does not fix the problem.

Comment: I suggest you [edit] your question to make the example code match your actual code, otherwise people will focus on problems that aren't actually problems.

Comment: Your last two sentences make this sound like a homework problem.  Start with a "Hello World" java program and work your way up.  However, SO is not here to help with homework.  Also, it is better to put more information (like the error message) in your subject line, so more people will be inclined to look at it.  Many people skip over generic "help me" subject lines.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, your code is in a file named "Main.java". From the code you posted, the class name is "movieFile". These two things need to match. You can fix this by either renaming your *file* to "movieFile.java", or renaming the *class* to "Main".

Separately, your method definition is not valid. Try changing this:

```
public static void (String[] args)
```

to this:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
```

Comment: And since it declared to be in a package named movieTheater, the source code must be in a directory named "movieTheater".